# How do I animate a curve with a build modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image: Build modifier being applied to curve]

I am trying to replicate what is happening in this gif.  I am using blender 2.81 (in addition to an addon) to import gcode (3d printing instructions) as a mesh.  I am then supposed to convert this mesh into a curve, increase the depth, and add a build modifier.  The problem is that I consistently encounter an error message telling me that I can't add a build modifier to a curve.  I have partially gotten around this by converting the curve back into a mesh.  The issue is that the build animation then comes in somewhat fragmented.
[image]
Is there any way to have this animate cleanly, as though it were being 3d printed (or like a cake being iced)?  I am very new to blender.  Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: if i create a curve and add a build modifier ...it just works. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exa1o.gif did you try that? (without converting to mesh)

Comment: and adding a link where you got that gif from....would be helpful

Comment: https://github.com/Heinz-Loepmeier/Blender-Gcode-Import/wiki#animation-of-the-print-with-blenders-build-modifier

Comment: I just tried it with a bezier curve, with no luck though. I get the error "Transform curve to mesh in order to apply constructive modifiers"

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I was running blender 2.81 to get the plugin working.  This problem seems to be corrected in the newest blender iteration